# Как вызвать функцию при создании Stateful виджета?

Tags: flutter, dart

Создаю Stateful Widget, нужно при создании вызвать функцию generate, не подскажете как сделать?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class New extends StatefulWidget {
  bool flag;
  Image image;
  String name;
  String text;
  String author;
  DateTime date;
  New({this.flag, this.image, this.name, this.text, this.author, this.date});
  @override
  _NewState createState() => _NewState();
}

class _NewState extends State<New> {
  generate() {
    if (widget.flag == false) {   //<-------- вот эту функцию нужно вызвать при создании виджета
      print('FALSE FLAG');
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переопределите метод initSate и вызывайте:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  generate();
}
```